# [CALayer retain]: message sent to deallocated instance?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, view, transition

In my app when I am switching views, after about the 4th time I switch views I get a crash that says:

```
*** -[CALayer retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6c4ba0
```

I have NSZombieEnabled in Xcode and it points me to this line whenever it switches views:

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

Also if I do a backtrace of the (gdb) it gives me this:

```
#0  0x37dd68a0 in ___forwarding___ ()
#1  0x37d31680 in __forwarding_prep_0___ ()
#2  0x37d1d026 in CFRetain ()
#3  0x37d26bb2 in +[__NSArrayI __new::] ()
#4  0x37d26acc in -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:] ()
#5  0x3518e680 in -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:] ()
#6  0x3518e7a4 in -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:] ()
#7  0x3534c40c in __UIViewWillBeRemovedFromSuperview ()
#8  0x3518dad0 in -[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview] ()
#9  0x000368a6 in __block_global_1 (.block_descriptor=<value temporarily unavailable, due to optimizations>, finished=1 '\001') at /Users/bobsComputer/Desktop/Projects/NewApp/MyApp/MyApp3/MyApp3ViewController.mm:135
#10 0x351a70be in -[UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate _didEndBlockAnimation:finished:context:] ()
#11 0x351a181a in -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] ()
#12 0x351a6fb8 in -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] ()
#13 0x3354fba6 in CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks ()
#14 0x37a91f7a in _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp ()
#15 0x37da72dc in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#16 0x37d2a4dc in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#17 0x37d2a3a4 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#18 0x378a8fcc in GSEventRunModal ()
#19 0x351ba742 in UIApplicationMain ()
```

Also this how I switch views, I have a main view controller. I then use a ParentView and protocols to call these methods from my other views controllers. I then use custom UIView animations to switch views.

Does anyone have any ideas why this is crashing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-[UIView addSubview:]` causes the subview to be retained, and `-[UIView removeFromSuperview]` causes the view to be released. This is direct from [Apple's UIView documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html). At that point, one of your objects needs to retain the CALayer or it will be deallocated.

I assumed that the CALayer was created by you directly. All UIViews are associated with CALayers; the CALayer is what a UIView draws into, and then its CALayer is composited onto the screen. If you're not working with CALayers directly, this is a symptom of another problem.

The core problem you're describing is an overrelease. It's possible you're not retaining a UIView when you should. I suggest you run the Xcode analyzer (in Xcode 4, choose the Product > Analyze) menu item and see what gets reported. Pay special attention to all of the memory management errors it reports.

Comment: What is the CALayer though, does that mean UIView? If so what do you mean, like [[view1 addSubview:view2] retain]; ?

Comment: Analyze does not report anything though :(

Comment: Can you use the debugger to determine the delegate of the CALayer? The delegate will be the object (often a UIView) that tells the CALayer when to draw. I haven't encountered a problem like this myself, but in the debugger, you would do something like "po [(CALayer *)0x6c4ba0 delegate]" (this is using the address from your above example). Perhaps if you identify which object is the delegate of the CALayer, it will eventually point to the source of the problem.

Comment: How about this, is there any alternative to removeFromSuperview that does not cause the view to get released?

Comment: No, having the view released by removeFromSuperview is correct behavior. You need to retain the object according to Objective-C's memory management guidelines (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html).

Comment: How would I retain self.view then to make sure it never gets released because in my app, I need to have that view never released.

Comment: How is self.view declared? As an objective-c property, you should declare it as retained, and have synthesized accessors. This means that whatever class 'self' is will retain it.

Comment: I don't declare it, it is the view controller's view.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I was not using Interface Builder for my views. The cause was that a subview of the view that was causing the crash was being released twice (but not crashing upon the second release weirdly enough). So I would suggest you go into the view's initWithFrame method, or wherever you are adding your subviews to it and look at every release carefully. I usually do not implement the dealloc method since I am sending an autorelease message to every subview before I add it to the parent view. In this way i have less places to look at and I m sure that everything will be released once the parent view is discarded. Hope that helps...